# Need source for the inverse of "Clarke's Third Law"

Tags: magic, quotes, arthur-c-clarke

I'm looking for the source of a quote that is the *inverse* of the third of  [Clarke's Three Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws).  It was in a book, article or short story from the late 1990's to early 2000's.

I remember that the quote says something like this:

- "Any sufficiently organized form of magic is indistinguishable from technology."

I know about the [Girl-Genius reference](https://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20081205), and I feel certain that isn't the first time I heard or read the quote.

Comment: Not a short story, but the WizBiz series includes a number of variants and refactorings of Clarke's Third Law.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain [this](https://comicslate.org/en/sci-fi/freefall/0255) really satisfies the inverse, but I've remembered it for over twenty years now, it seems.

Comment: @clarkitext, your post didn't really give enough to be an answer in it's own right, but I'd didnt want it to be completely lost. Feel free to repost it if you can source each quote and give dates etc.

Comment: Battlefield - Dr Who, as a deleted scene and in the novelization by Ben Aaronovitch.

Comment: I think I know the book the original poster is referring to, but I cannot find it's name. It is a story about what appears to be an alien invasion. The invasion starts with a heavy rain. The rain becomes milky. Then there is a mist. The main characters must protect children to survive. The "aliens" are a biblical plague which comes to earth every few millennia and kills off humans except those who protect children. I am looking for the book also, but cannot remember it's name or it's author.

Comment: Hi @Irishlostboy, welcome to SF&F.  I'm afraid that without providing a work and a date this doesn't really answer the question.  What you might do is ask a question to get the story you're thinking of identified, and then If it fits you could post it as an answer here.

Comment: The inverse is "any technology that is distinguishable from magic is insufficiently advanced".

Answer (score 35):

This was quoted in the [Fall 1989 edition of the *Keystone Folklore Archives*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000010068769&view=1up&seq=34&q1=composed). It *also* appears somewhat earlier in the [1984 edition of *Keystone Folklore*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Keystone_Folklore/VzZLAAAAYAAJ?kptab=editions&gbpv=1&bsq=indistinguishable), identified as being on page 26 in "Volumes 2-4" whatever that means.

It's worthy of note that they've identified it not as their own quote, but rather something that button-makers had been putting onto pin and buttons sold at scifi fairs for several years prior.

> **“Reality is a Crutch for People Who Can’t Deal With Science Fiction:”**
>
> Fans intend for buttons of this land to invite comment. Comments can
> come in the form of talk, and often do, but since buttons can be
> obtained quickly at science fiction conventions, comments on buttons
> can also come in the form of alternative buttons. Some of these
> running button dialogues have been preserved and extended beyond their
> originators by their inclusion in button catalogs. For example, a
> statement by science fiction author, Arthur C. Clark, became a button:
> “Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from
> magic.” This, in turn, inspired a series of fan-composed corollary
> slogans:
>
> - **Any sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from technology**
> - Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from a rigged demo.

Comment: Warning - that link is a rabbit hole. Seriously.

Comment: I prefer the contrapositive formulation: "Any technology distinguishable from magic is insufficiently advanced."

Comment: Isn't it "Any sufficiently *analysed* magic is indistinguishable from technology"

Comment: I've never heard of this journal before this answer, and I'm pretty sure this wasn't an academic source

Comment: As a response to the saying "Never attribute to malice that which can be explained by incompetence." I've used "Any sufficiently advanced incompetence is indistinguishable from malice".

Comment: **Any sufficiently rigged demo is magic.**

Comment: Any successful demo is magic.

Comment: Google Books pushes this same source back to the date of 1984. I've edited the Answer.

Comment: @RossPresser - Cheers. That's a lot earlier.

Comment: And let's not forget Niven's Corollary: Any technology you don't understand may as well be magic.

Answer (score 20):

The 1986 Infocom game *Trinity* by Dave Lebling has the line "Any sufficiently arcane magic is indistinguishable from technology."

From @pll in comments:
The full game code is on Github [here](https://github.com/the-infocom-files/trinity), and the quotes in question appear [here](https://github.com/the-infocom-files/trinity/blob/7eb27f9a7cc429fb79d1bd1032369939afeec946/places.zil#L6719), as 2 of 13 that can appear.

Comment: I didn't play a lot of these games back in the day.

Comment: Are you certain?  I just did a run-through and that text never appeared.  (I didn't find it in the manual either.)

Comment: In truth I am not sure which game now. I definitely remember seeing the line somewhere, and Wikipedia claims that it was in Trinity, so I wrote that. I'll try to find where it really is.

Comment: Confirmed, it's in Trinity. I TXD'd the Z4 file and I see the two epigraphs, Clarke and Lebling.  Pastebin excerpt: https://pastebin.com/u3N2HXqg

Comment: Nice.  There must be more quotes than they show in a single run-through.

Comment: @DavidW : The full game code is on Github [here](https://github.com/the-infocom-files/trinity), and the quotes in question appear [here](https://github.com/the-infocom-files/trinity/blob/7eb27f9a7cc429fb79d1bd1032369939afeec946/places.zil#L6719), as 2 of 13 that can appear.

Comment: @pll  it's definitely worth you or the OP adding that to the answer with an [edit].

Answer (score 10):

I only found a snippet in a Google books search, but "[Indian Summa](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2193360)" by Arlan Andrews in *Analog*, January 1989 uses the quote:

> Ross understood and laughed aloud. We shouted it out together: **“Any sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from technology!"**

Combined with Valorum's quote above and the appearance (in print) of Gehm's Corollary ("Any technology distinguishable from magic is insufficiently advanced.") in 1991, it would appear that these ideas were probably well-established in fandom by 1989 at the latest.

Comment: What you refer to as "Gehm's Corollary" seems to be a late citation.  I was using this in my teaching and corporate presentations starting in September of 1984 (my earliest hard-copy reference; it might have been as early as 1980), and still use it today.  I would be surprised were I the first person to think of it, as the application to high-tech endeavours is fairly straightforward.  I haven't found an earlier citation -- but given the large time gap from Clark's 3rd, I assume that there is one.

Answer (score 8):

The quote has definitely been used by Terry Pratchett. The one case I'm pretty confident with is [The Science Of Discworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Science_of_Discworld) from 1999. I would put good money on there being an earlier use by Pterry, given that the wizards (after the introduction of Ponder Stibbons) are explicitly carrying out this trope, but I can't immediately go looking for a source.

As other answers say, there are earlier uses of the phrase, but none of them are exactly bestsellers. This makes it more likely that Pratchett was where you first found it.

Comment: hmm..I haven't actually read any of Discworld, but i have friends who loved it long ago.  I'll look it up

Comment: The later *Science of Discworld* books definitely use this, but it's a long time since I read the first

Comment: I accidentally googled my way into a pirate copy. It quotes Clarke's law, attributes ‘Any technology distinguishable from magic is insufficiently advanced’ to Gregory Benford, and tweaks the original to refer to "physics", but doesn't contain this inverse (I was expecting the "inverse" to refer to Benford's version

Comment: The quote is also used in the web-comic "Girl Genius" at least once. But Science of Discworld came out most of a decade earlier.

Comment: It dates from well before Pratchett used it. While he did do good turns of phrases, he isn't responsible for every one that exists.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be referring to a Sci Fi short story named 'The Taking' by Dean Koontz. It is about the coming of real evil to rip the fruits of sin on earth while people mistake it for an alien invasion with sufficiently advanced technology. The author himself comes up with the inverse of Arthur Clarke's quotation, if I remember correctly. The exact quote is by Molly, one of the protagonists:

"New thought: A supernatural event of world-shaking proportions, occurring in a faithless time when only science is believed to have the power to work miracles, might appear to be the work of an extraterrestrial species hundreds or even thousands of years more advanced than we are."

Comment: This was suggested before, but ultimately deleted because the poster couldn't find a quote that matched what the question was looking for.